# Corda query with aggregate functions

Tags: corda

i want to count number of rows in fungible_token table.  (Corda_OS 4.4 TokenSDK 1.2)
here is my code

```
@StartableByRPC
class Count : FlowLogic<String>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()
    @Suspendable
    @Throws(FlowException::class)
    override fun call():String{
        val generalCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
        val count =PersistentFungibleToken::amount.count()
        val countCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(count)
        val criteria = generalCriteria.and(countCriteria)
        val queryBy: Vault.Page<FungibleToken> = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(criteria, PageSpecification())
        val resutCount = queryBy.otherResults[0] as Long
        return  "total : ${resutCount}"
    }
}
```

it have 4 rows in  fungible_token table (one record has been consumed  )
Expected results = 4 ,but the result = 3
i check my postgresql log ,find this query

```
select
  count(persistent1_.amount) as col_0_0_ 
from
  vault_states vaultschem0_ 
  cross join fungible_token persistent1_ 
where
  (vaultschem0_.contract_state_class_name in ('com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.states.FungibleToken')) 
  and vaultschem0_.state_status = 0
  and ( 
    vaultschem0_.output_index
    , vaultschem0_.transaction_id
  ) = ( 
    persistent1_.output_index
    , persistent1_.transaction_id
  ) 
limit
 201
```

Vault.StateStatus.ALL doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it a bit more complicated. What you are trying to achieve can be done with a simple query :

```
 QueryCriteria countCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(
     Builder.count(QueryCriteriaUtils.getField("amount", PersistentFungibleToken.class)),
     Vault.StateStatus.ALL
 );
 Vault.Page<FungibleToken> fungibleTokenPage = 
     activeParty.vaultQueryByCriteria(countCriteria, FungibleToken.class);
```

The issue however in the previous composite query is that VaultCustomQueryCriteria initializes with status as unconsumed if not specified.